# Trying to get many to many to work with Rails and Emberjs

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ember.js, active-model-serializers

I'm trying to get many to many associations to work with Ember JS and Rails but it doesn't seem to be rendering the `Role Name`

Below are the files:

**users/index.hbs**

```
{{#each}}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{id}}</td>
                    <td>{{email}}</td>
                    <td>{{title}}</td>
                    <td>{{first_name}}</td>
                    <td>{{last_name}}</td>
                    <td>{{position}}</td>
                    <td>{{work_phone}}</td>
                    <td>{{company}}</td>
                    <td>{{sign_in_count}}</td>
                    <td>{{last_sign_in_ip}}</td>
                    <td>{{confirmed_at}}</td>
                    <td>{{created_at}}</td>
                    <td>
                        {{#each role in roles}}
                            {{role.name}}
                        {{/each}}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {{#linkTo 'user' this class='btn btn-sm btn-primary'}}Show{{/linkTo}}
                        <a href="javascript:;" {{action delete this}} class="text-danger">Delete</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                {{/each}}
```

**user.js.coffee**

```
VirtualExhibition.User = DS.Model.extend
    email: DS.attr 'string'
    password: DS.attr 'string'
    title: DS.attr 'string'
    first_name: DS.attr 'string'
    last_name: DS.attr 'string'
    position: DS.attr 'string'
    work_phone: DS.attr 'string'
    company: DS.attr 'string'
    sign_in_count: DS.attr 'number'
    last_sign_in_ip: DS.attr 'string'
    confirmed_at: DS.attr 'date'
    created_at: DS.attr 'date'
    venue: DS.hasMany 'VirtualExhibition.Venue'
    roles: DS.belongsTo 'VirtualExhibition.Role'
```

**role.js.coffee**

```
VirtualExhibition.Role = DS.Model.extend
    id: DS.attr 'number'
    name: DS.attr 'string'
    users: DS.hasMany 'VirtualExhibition.User'
```

**user_serializer.rb**

```
class UserSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :email, :title, :first_name, :last_name, :position, :work_phone, :company, :sign_in_count, :last_sign_in_ip, :confirmed_at, :created_at
  has_many :roles, embed: :ids
end
```

**role_serializer.rb**

```
class RoleSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :name
  has_many :users, embed: :ids
end
```

I'm getting `role_ids` as arrays as expected from my Rails application.

But I'm not sure why I'm not getting anything from `{{role.name}}`

Why is this the case?

**JSON**

```
{
users: [
{
id: 2,
email: "example1@gmail.com",
title: "Mr",
first_name: "AA",
last_name: "BB",
position: "Web Dev",
work_phone: "12314",
company: "CC",
sign_in_count: 0,
last_sign_in_ip: null,
confirmed_at: null,
created_at: "2013-11-08T14:27:32.401Z",
role_ids: [
4
]
},
{
id: 3,
email: "example2@example.com",
title: null,
first_name: "Host",
last_name: "Host",
position: null,
work_phone: null,
company: null,
sign_in_count: 0,
last_sign_in_ip: null,
confirmed_at: "2013-11-11T11:09:16.796Z",
created_at: "2013-11-11T11:09:16.832Z",
role_ids: [
1
]
},
{
id: 4,
email: "info@ggg.com.au",
title: null,
first_name: "Visitor",
last_name: "Visitor",
position: null,
work_phone: null,
company: null,
sign_in_count: 0,
last_sign_in_ip: null,
confirmed_at: "2013-11-11T11:09:17.123Z",
created_at: "2013-11-11T11:09:17.125Z",
role_ids: [
2
]
},
{
id: 1,
email: "aaa@saa.com.au",
title: "Mr",
first_name: "Hi",
last_name: "Hello",
position: "Web Developer",
work_phone: "123456",
company: "Comp",
sign_in_count: 11,
last_sign_in_ip: "127.0.0.1",
confirmed_at: "2013-10-29T12:26:00.583Z",
created_at: "2013-10-29T12:23:25.453Z",
role_ids: [
3
]
}
]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some errors in your configuration:

**user.js.coffee**

```
VirtualExhibition.User = DS.Model.extend
    email: DS.attr 'string'
    password: DS.attr 'string'
    title: DS.attr 'string'
    first_name: DS.attr 'string'
    last_name: DS.attr 'string'
    position: DS.attr 'string'
    work_phone: DS.attr 'string'
    company: DS.attr 'string'
    sign_in_count: DS.attr 'number'
    last_sign_in_ip: DS.attr 'string'
    confirmed_at: DS.attr 'date'
    created_at: DS.attr 'date'        
    venue: DS.hasMany 'venue', async: true
    # here I think that you want hasMany instead of belongsTo, additionally the async: true is needed, since your are fetching the data using ajax.
    # and instead of "VirtualExhibition.Role" you need to use just "role"
    roles: DS.hasMany 'role', async: true
```

**JSON**

```
{
    id: 2,
    email: "example1@gmail.com",
    ...        
    created_at: "2013-11-08T14:27:32.401Z",
    // use roles instead of roles_id
    roles: [
        4
    ]
}
```

This is the fiddle with the updated code http://jsfiddle.net/marciojunior/MKu46/

In addition I recommend you to give a look in the [DS.ActiveModelAdapter](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/activemodel-adapter/lib/system/active_model_adapter.js), to get a best integration with rails active model serializers.

Comment: As soon as I change hasMany to lowercase without `VirtualExhibition` it doesn't seem to be working. Is there a reason why? It seems I need to have `VirtualExhibition.Venue` or `VirtualExhibition.Role`

Comment: Hmm strange. What is the ember data version?

Comment: DEBUG: ------------------------------- application.js:5533
DEBUG: Ember      : 1.1.0 application.js:5533
DEBUG: Handlebars : 1.0.0 application.js:5533
DEBUG: jQuery     : 2.0.3 application.js:5533
DEBUG: -------------------------------

Comment: Where can I find Ember-data version in my Rails app?

Comment: This is what I have in the `Gemfile.lock` ember-data-source (0.14)

Comment: So your ember data version is 0.14. Strange doesn't appear in the console. In ember data 0.14 the relationship model, need to use the full name, in your case "VirtualExhibition.Venue". And doesn't need `async: true`.

Comment: I recommend you to update when possible to the last version `1.0.0-beta.X` it's more simple and you can use the ActiveModelAdapter. The transition guide is [here](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/TRANSITION.md)

Comment: ember-data-source only deals with 0.14 is there a way to get 1.0.0 for Rails? Could there be any Gem to get this or should I just add them manually as part of Asset Pipeline Vendor?

Comment: Try to add `gem 'ember-data-source', '~> 1.0.0.beta.3'`

Answer (score 0):

The template has a typo, should be each **role** in roles, *singular word*

```
                    {{#each role in roles}}
                        {{role.name}}
                    {{/each}}
```

And you should sideload roles

```
{
    users: [
        {
        id: 2,
        email: "example1@gmail.com",
        title: "Mr",
        first_name: "AA",
        last_name: "BB",
        position: "Web Dev",
        work_phone: "12314",
        company: "CC",
        sign_in_count: 0,
        last_sign_in_ip: null,
        confirmed_at: null,
        created_at: "2013-11-08T14:27:32.401Z",
        role_ids: [
        4
        ]
        },
        { more users...}
    ],
    roles: [
        {role object},
        {role object}
    ]
}
```

Or define your Hasmany relation as async

```
VirtualExhibition.User = DS.Model.extend
email: DS.attr 'string'
password: DS.attr 'string'
title: DS.attr 'string'
first_name: DS.attr 'string'
last_name: DS.attr 'string'
position: DS.attr 'string'
work_phone: DS.attr 'string'
company: DS.attr 'string'
sign_in_count: DS.attr 'number'
last_sign_in_ip: DS.attr 'string'
confirmed_at: DS.attr 'date'
created_at: DS.attr 'date'
venue: DS.belongsTo 'VirtualExhibition.Venue'
roles: DS.hasMany 'VirtualExhibition.Role',{async:true}
```

Good luck

Comment: Can you post a Copy of the json you are receiving

Comment: I just pasted JSON that are being received by user model